# How to Align first and Extract second - Face Alignment using RetinaFace without black areas

Tags: alignment, extract, detection, face-detection

[Extracted Image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLduL.png) I'm trying to use RetinaFace to do face detection, face alignment, face extraction and file cropping for situations when the head is tilted or is in other position than vertical.

I do have the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_path = "/content/drive/img/0036.jpg"
faces = RetinaFace.extract_faces(img_path, align = True)
for face in faces:
  plt.imshow(face)
  plt.show()
```

So, how to do the alignment first and only after that the extraction second, and eventually the cropping third? I want to avoid to have those odd black areas on the corners (as in the attached image), who only represent missing data areas that could be important?

I've tried MTCNN and Dlib, but it didn't work for me, I was getting loads of error and I discovered that RetinaFace is doing face alignment and face extraction very simple, with only one line of code. The only thing isn't doing it in the right order to avoid loss of data, through adding black areas.
Also, there should be a way, which I haven't discover yet, to make the bounding box for the detected faces to be align with the eye line, not with the image/photo edges (which is vertical).

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it with core RetinaFace functions. You basically need to align first and detect facial area second.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from retinaface import RetinaFace
from retinaface.commons import postprocess

# define the target path
img_path = "img11.jpg"

# find landmarks with retinaface ()
result = RetinaFace.detect_faces(img_path)
landmarks = result["face_1"]["landmarks"]
left_eye = landmarks["left_eye"]
right_eye = landmarks["right_eye"]
nose = landmarks["nose"]

# align the original image with respect to the eye coordinates
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img_aligned = postprocess.alignment_procedure(img, right_eye, left_eye, nose)
img_aligned = img_aligned[:,:,::-1]
# plt.imshow(img_aligned)
# plt.show()

# detect facial area on the alreday aligned image
faces = RetinaFace.extract_faces(img_aligned)
plt.imshow(faces[0][:,:,::-1])
plt.show()
```

[image: output of the program snippet]